PyCharm giving error on SCSS format in CSS file
My PyCharm subscription recently expired and went into fallback mode version 2023.1.6. Earlier it could read SCSS format in .css file and provided full support as expected. After reverting to the fallback version, it's giving errors and expecting a strict CSS format.
Here's a screenshot for reference:

The error on line 8 expects a }.
I have tried installing a few plugins and even a SCSS/LESS file watcher but none of them worked.
Please suggest how this can be resolved.

So what kind of file is this? The file extension? Show how the IDE identifies is: 1) the file icon it uses; 2) The file type it uses (locate the file in a Project panel and invoke "View | Quick Documentation" on it -- post the screenshot of that.

Right now (based on this rather limited info) this looks like a new "nested CSS" format that CSS/browsers started to support recently. Old IDE version will not support this. Possible workaround could be in telling the IDE to treat your .css files as PostCSS instead of the standard CSS. Have a look at Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Style Sheets | Dialects

Awesome. Thank you so much. This worked like a charm.
